# SSRS REPORT FOR MS CRM 2013 - fetch data month wise for last 12 months and current date

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2013

I need to create a SSRS report for contract records in pending status (13 months data until current month).
Requirement is to fetch all months when the status of the record was pending irrespective of the current status.

I have use 2 hidden pending dates on form for this: Pending Start Date and Pending End Date.

On CRM form , I have implemented this using JavaScript:-

1. When the status changes to Pending (and the Pending Start Date is
   blank), then current date should be populated in Pending Start Date.
   If there is a date already, do not overwrite.
2. When the status changes to Won/Lost/Declined/Abandoned, the Pending
   End date needs to be populated (if the date is blank only) with
   current date.

Then in SSRS report, I need to count the records that are in Pending state for each month until the prior month from the Pending end date.

For example, if Pending start was Oct 7 and Pending End was Jan 10, then you will count for October, November, and December. If pending start was Oct 7 and Pending End was Oct 20, then do not count that.

Please help/advice.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with ? The SSRS design on how to display, the fetch xml or maybe the stored procedure for the data fetch?
Note that for the dates auto population, it is always better to use a workflow instead of JavaScript. As most probably something else might change the status of the contract too, too like a workflow, plugin or external code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on date auto population.Actually I am not able to design a query/stored procedure to achive this. It seems like fetching an audit data for last 1 year or so.

Comment: Is this an on premise CRM so SQL queries can be used? Because if it is online you would need to use fetch xml, which would a bit complicated.

Comment: This is a on premise version we are using.